# Selecting a cell within the last row of a pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro that gives me the value of cell D of the last row within a pivot table. This is the code I have so far.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim Can As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Range

Set Can = Worksheets("Can")
Set PT = Can.PivotTables("Can Table")

Set Flight1 = Can.Range(("D14"), ("D" & Rows.Count)).End(xlDown)

Can.Range("AC15") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Flight1)

End Sub
```

This macro works fine until I start playing around with the pivot table. Since there are some cells within the pivot table that have no value, the code I have right now will identify the last row up until the no value cell. What I want is the very last row of the pivot table (aka the "Grand Total"). How do I choose the last row of the pivot table to disregard any cell within the pivot table that may have no value?

Thanks

G

Comment: What is the Header of the of column "D" ? what is the name of the `pivotField` you have set in your `PivotTable` that is located in column "D"?  Also, if this code is placed in your `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, why do you set `Set Can = Worksheets("Can")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pivottable [TableRange1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivottable-tablerange1-property-excel) property

Adapt the below as required

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim Can As Worksheet
    Dim Flight1 As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set Can = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Can")

    With Can

        Set PT = .PivotTables("Can Table")    'change as appropriate

        lastRow = .Range(Split(PT.TableRange1.Address(0, 0), ":")(1)).Row

        If lastRow >= 14 Then
            Set Flight1 = Can.Range("D14:D" & lastRow)
        Else
            Debug.Print "Last row is before start row of 14"
        End If

    End With

    If Not Flight1 Is Nothing Then Debug.Print Flight1.Address

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the last row is very shaky using End(xlDown)
Try

```
("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
```

The only problem I could see id if you had data below your pivot table

Comment: This doesnt work when there is a cell within a pivot table that has no value in it. Like when the cell is blank. I basically want the value that is in the "Grand Total" part of the pivot table